# PostgreSQL- How to use GROUP BY/ ORDER BY on DATE and keep a to_char column in the result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table from which I need to extract data GROUPED by dates and ORDERED BY DATES DESC but I also need the date as a string.

```
SELECT to_char(TRANSACTED AT TIME ZONE '{session['time_zone_3']}', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date,  SUM(glasses) AS glasses, SUM(sleep) AS sleep, SUM(calories) AS calories 
FROM history  
GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I was using this but it doesn't work as I want it to because `date` is just a string a so it puts 30/8 before 1/9.

Then, I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (to_char(TRANSACTED AT TIME ZONE '{session['time_zone_3']}', 'DD-MM-YYYY')) date,  SUM(glasses) AS glasses, SUM(sleep) AS sleep, SUM(calories) AS calories 
FROM history 
GROUP BY DATE(history.TRANSACTED) 
ORDER BY DATE(history.TRANSACTED);
```

which gives this error:

> RuntimeError: column "date" does not exist

I tried a few other things from different StackOverflow posts, but i couldn't really get there.

My table history's columns:

- TRANSACTED = TIMESTAMPZ
- Calories (int)
- glasses(int)
- sleep(int)

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

You can use an aggregation function.  For instance:

```
ORDER BY MIN(Transacted) DESC
```

(I don't think the time zone makes a difference for this.)

Comment: I want to keep the `date` column without including it in the GROUP BY or ORDER BY and can't think of an aggregate function to put it in, DISTINCT didn't work out.

Comment: @ManaswiSharma . . . You can keep your query.  Just change the `ORDER BY` to use an aggregation function.  This is referring to your first query.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to do with the format you defined for `date`. Try below where we use `YYYY-MM-DD` format for the `order by` clause

```
SELECT to_char(TRANSACTED AT TIME ZONE '{session['time_zone_3']}', 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS date,
       SUM(glasses) AS glasses, 
       SUM(sleep) AS sleep, 
       SUM(calories) AS calories 
FROM history  
GROUP BY to_char(TRANSACTED AT TIME ZONE '{session['time_zone_3']}', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(TRANSACTED AT TIME ZONE '{session['time_zone_3']}','YYYY-MM-DD') DESC;
```